# Where can I find a good article or book about Visual Studio 2010 team foundation?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I need some sources like articles and books about visual studio 2010 team foundation features. something which describes:

1. What are the new features of 2010 team foundation
2. How to use team foundation server
3. best practices

thank you in advance.

Comment: there are also youtube videos for TFS (tutorial videos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Visual Studio TFS Branching Guide 2010](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=tfsbranchingguideiii) (this contains pretty much everthing you need to know about branching/versioning scenarios)

[Team Foundation Server 2010 - Cool new features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dannawi/team-foundation-server-2010-cool-new-features)

[Team Foundation Server 2010 Key Concepts](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/bharry/team-foundation-server-2010-key-concepts/)

Answer (score 0):

How about Microsofts [What's New in Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386063.aspx) and [What's New for Application Lifecycle Management in Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385832.aspx)